# Using $wpdb as an alternative to WordPress meta_query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a WordPress-based events website. Each event needs to have up to three date ranges applied to it (I've added these with the `Advanced Custom Fields` plug-in). The events are displayed on a simple page with a date and category filter. I tried this using a `meta_query`, but it's incredibly slow (see code below). I now understand this is a known-issue. So basically, I'm looking for an alternative. From what I read, `$wpdb` is a possible solution, but I don't have much experience with this.

Any help much appreciated. Thank you.

```
$events = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'category_name' => $category_list,
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'OR',

array('relation' => 'AND', array('key' => 'event_start_date_1',  'compare' => '<=', 'value' => $date, 'type' => 'DATE'), array('key' => 'event_finish_date_1', 'compare' => '>=', 'value' => $date, 'type' => 'DATE'),
),

array('relation' => 'AND', array('key' => 'event_start_date_2',  'compare' => '<=', 'value' => $date, 'type' => 'DATE'),array('key' => 'event_finish_date_2', 'compare' => '>=', 'value' => $date, 'type' => 'DATE'),
),

array('relation' => 'AND', array('key' => 'event_start_date_3',  'compare' => '<=', 'value' => $date, 'type' => 'DATE'), array('key' => 'event_finish_date_3', 'compare' => '>=', 'value' => $date, 'type' => 'DATE'),
),

),
));
```

**Update**

The following appears to work

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta m1, $wpdb->postmeta m2, $wpdb->term_relationships, $wpdb->term_taxonomy, $wpdb->terms

WHERE 

$wpdb->posts.ID = m1.post_id AND $wpdb->posts.ID = m2.post_id 
AND $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
AND $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id


AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->terms.slug IN ('$category_list')

AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'

AND 
(

((m1.meta_key = 'event_start_date_1' AND m1.meta_value <= '$date') AND (m2.meta_key = 'event_finish_date_1' AND m2.meta_value >= '$date'))
OR
((m1.meta_key = 'event_start_date_2' AND m1.meta_value <= '$date') AND (m2.meta_key = 'event_finish_date_2' AND m2.meta_value >= '$date'))
OR
((m1.meta_key = 'event_start_date_3' AND m1.meta_value <= '$date') AND (m2.meta_key = 'event_finish_date_3' AND m2.meta_value >= '$date'))
OR
((m1.meta_key = 'event_start_date_4' AND m1.meta_value <= '$date') AND (m2.meta_key = 'event_finish_date_4' AND m2.meta_value >= '$date'))

)

GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
```

I'm not sure this is the most efficient solution, so any suggestions for improvements welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**(Try)Hope that helps:--**

modify the where clause to filter meta data

```
  add_filter('posts_where', array($this, 'filter_meta_query_where'));
```

join the meta table to the posts query

```
add_filter('posts_join' , array($this, 'filter_meta_join'));
```

This is the main function that adds the meta query (I've added conditions for schedules_port, you'll have to build the rest yourself the way you want):--

```
function filter_meta_query_where($where = '')
{
    global $wpdb; 
    global $wp_query;
    global $sf_form_data;

    if(!is_admin())
    {
        $where .= " AND (($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'schedules_port' AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%$sfrom%' OR $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%$sto%')))";
    }

    return $where;
}
```

And here's the code for the join:--

```
function filter_meta_join($join)
{
     global $wpdb;

     $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id ";

     return $join;
}
```